# How to display element from another website?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a widget, which displays element (div) from another website (I have access). For example: On website.com/?clientName=Mike will be element with informations for my client Mike. Mike (and want to add this element to his website (I want to add element without background, so iFrame falls off). It should be responsible for each website.

How can I do this?

Comment: So, basically, you want what an iframe does, but without iframe? What do you mean "I have access" ? Are you sure cross-domains blockings will be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make a page with that DIV and call it from the both websites.

For example make an element page like website.com/person.php (asp,..)?clientName=Mike :

which return :

```
<div>Mike information</div>
```

and then in both websites make a div:

```
<div id="personDiv"></div>
<script>
$.post( "website.com/person.php", { clientName: "Mike"})
  .done(function( personInfo ) {
    $("#personDiv").html( personInfo );
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is jQuery's [get](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

```
<div id="target"></div>

$.get("yourPage.html", null, function(text) {
  $("#target").html($(text).find("#yourElement"));
});
```